# sharing via wifi an internet connection obtained via bluetooth

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, bluetooth, netsh

I have a working internet connection on my w8.1 laptop, this connection is done via a bluetooth network connection to my iPhone, in tethering.

I'd like to share this connection via wifi to my other appliances.

I know how to setup an hosted network

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=”mynetworkX” key=”12345678”   
netsh wlan start
```

my devices connect happily to mynetworkX but they have no internet access.

the problem is that I should share my bluetooth network connection (the one I use to connect to the internet) to mynetworkX, but there is no "sharing" tab on its property pages.
is there any way to enable the sharing of a bluetooth network connection? maybe using netsh or some other tool?

thank you.

Comment: can you list the complete steps of this setup so I can try it on my pc and get back to you.

Comment: to set up the tethering

-turn on bluetooth and personal hotspot on my iphone

-on windows: find bluetooth devices, found my iphone, right click connect as - access point.

-the bluetooth network connection is estabilished, and my laptop exits on internet happily

to set up a n hosted network, the two netsh commands above are enough.

Comment: IT's also not working for me i think the problem is with DNS, i did the setup using this tutorial for my iphone and it's working perfectly for like 5 months. http://ipod.about.com/od/iphonehowtos/ss/Use-Iphone-Personal-Hotspot_5.htm